# How can I get my anonymous JavaScript function to execute withing the calling scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

I'm trying to make a generic error message function that I can use within any `JavaScript` function.  This function would test for certain validity and stop the calling function dead-cold if it fails.

For example:

```
var fun = function() {
    var a = {};
    a.blah = 'Hello';

    checkIfExistErrorIfNot(a);         // fine, continue on...
    checkIfExistErrorIfNot(a.blah);    // fine, continue on...
    checkIfExistErrorIfNot(a.notDefined);    // error.  stop calling method ("fun") from continuing

    console.log('Yeah!  You made it here!');
}
```

This was my first stab at it:

```
var checkIfExistErrorIfNot(obj) {
    var msg = 'Object does not exist.';

    if(!obj) {
        return (function() {
            console.log(msg);
            return false;
        })();
    }

    return true;
}
```

The returning anonymous function executes just fine.  But the calling function still continues.  I'm guessing it's because the anon function does not execute in the scope of the calling function.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I may not have made my intentions clear.  Here is what I normally do in my methods:

```
saveData: function() {
    var store = this.getStore();
    var someObj = this.getOtherObject();

    if(!store || !someObj) {
        showError('There was an error');
        return false;   // now, 'saveData' will not continue
    }

    // continue on with save....
}
```

This is what I'd like to do:

```
saveData: function() {
    var store = this.getStore();
    var someObj = this.getOtherObject();

    checkIfExistErrorIfNot(store);
    checkIfExistErrorIfNot(someObj);

    // continue on with save....
}
```

Now, what would be even cooler would be:

```
...
    checkIfExistErrorIfNot( [store, someObj] );
...
```

And iterate through the array...cancelling on the first item that isn't defined.  But I could add the array piece if I can find out how to get the first part to work.

Thanks

Comment: You're calling "checkIfExistErrorIfNot" and *throwing away the return value.* Thus the `return` statements in that function have absolutely no effect on anything.

Comment: Do you want to `throw` an error or `return` an error signaling value?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I discovered.  lol

Comment: @Bergi what I actually want to do is stop executing the calling function ("fun" in this example).  The reason is that some of my functions load data stores, arrays, etc.  And having a ton of `if(datastore) {....` all over the place starts to look ugly.  I will sometimes put a `if(!datastore) {..exit..}` at the top.  Which is fine.  But I was just looking for a cleaner (as in, 'prettier') way of doing that.

Comment: @cbmeeks: Well, you can stop a function by two ways: raising an exceptions or returning early.

Comment: Returning early is what I normally do.  And, I'm trying to do the same thing.  But the returning early is being called from another method.  I'm not going to sweat it too much.  I just thought it might be convenient to have a syntax like illustrated above.

Comment: Throwing an exception would be the only way to have an impact on the code path of the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceptions for that:

```
var checkIfExistErrorIfNot = function (obj) {
    var msg = 'Object does not exist.';

    if(!obj) {
        throw new Error(msg);
    }
}

var fun = function() {
    var a = {};
    a.blah = 'Hello';

    try {
        console.log('a:');
        checkIfExistErrorIfNot(a);         // fine, continue on...
        console.log('a.blah:');
        checkIfExistErrorIfNot(a.blah);    // fine, continue on...
        console.log('a.notDefined:');
        checkIfExistErrorIfNot(a.notDefined);    // error.  stop calling method ("fun") from continuing
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }

    console.log('Yeah! You made it here!');
    return true;
}

console.log(fun());
```

Comment: Adding exceptions would certainly do it.  And I do something similar in other areas.  But the idea was to not even use the try/catch (or wrap it) so that "fun" would only have the one line.